# Spacy text classification using minibatch

Tags: python, text-classification, spacy, mini-batch

I have a question regarding the minibatching that is used in the example  [train_textcat.py](https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/examples/training/train_textcat.py)

The main training loop looks like this:

```py
for i in range(n_iter):
    losses = {}
    # batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
    batches = minibatch(train_data, size=compounding(4., 32., 1.001))
    for batch in batches:
        texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
        nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.2, losses=losses)
    with textcat.model.use_params(optimizer.averages):
        # evaluate on the dev data split off in load_data()
        scores = evaluate(nlp.tokenizer, textcat, dev_texts, dev_cats)
```

I was wondering why do all batches of the minibatch get consumed in one interation instead of consuming one batch per iteration of the main loop? Following code should expain what i mean.

```py
# batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
batches = minibatch(train_data, size=compounding(4., 32., 1.001))
for i, texts, annotations in zip(range(n_iter),*batch):
    losses = {}
    nlp.update(texts, annotations, sgd=optimizer, drop=0.2, losses=losses)
    with textcat.model.use_params(optimizer.averages):
        # evaluate on the dev data split off in load_data()
        scores = evaluate(nlp.tokenizer, textcat, dev_texts, dev_cats)
```

Thanks in advance!

### Your Environment

- **spaCy version:** 2.0.12
- **Platform:** Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
- **Python version:** 3.6.5
- **Models:** de

Answer (score 0):

Responce from an [issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3151) I opened with the same question:

> It's nice to have two loops, because the evaluation on the development
>   data should only happen once per epoch, not once per update ---
>   otherwise we'd be evaluating too often and it'd be slow.
>
> I also think there might be an implementation quirk of what you're
>   doing that's a bit worse. If you do the * unpacking, you have to
>   consume the generator and load everything into memory. This can be
>   worse than letting the minibatch generator stream, as you get in the
>   for loop.